# Setting up a MySQL table to track user link clicks

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is a followup to a question I posted a few days ago.

basically, I have a site with six links. In order to access the site, users must log in using LDAP authentication. When they do this, I grab some of their account credentials (username, firstname, lastname), and store it in a PHP $_SESSION variable.

That works; the user can log in, and the session data is being stored successfully.

Now, I want to set up a way to track which links have been clicked by what users. Basically just store a time stamp in the database of when they clicked the link. I want to be able to see who has (or has not) clicked each link, and when.

Can I do this in a single table / would that be a bad idea? I was thinking setting up the table like this:

TABLE (each bullet indicative of a column)

- auto-incrementing ID
- user account name: abc1234
- user account first name: John
- link 1: Last Accessed 5/2/2012 at 4:15PM
- link 2: NULL
- link 3: NULL
- link 4: Last Accessed 5/1/2012 at 2:20PM
- link 5: NULL
- link 6: NULL

basically the above would say that "John" had only clicked the first and 4th links. The rest are null because he has never accessed them. If he were to click #1 again, it would overwrite with the more recent date/time.

Can I do this in a single table? or will that create complications? I feel like the thing I will have the hardest time with is checking to see if the user is already in the database before adding the info (ie so that if John logs in a second time, a whole new row isn't created for him)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your site will absolutely never have more or less then 6 links ? If not, you have a part of the answer...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Hi, thanks for the input! You're right, I do not know that for a fact. I am doing this for a college page, and they have said that it will be exactly 6 links but it could definitely change in the future I bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a bad idea. What if you wanted to have a seventh link? What if the user format would change?

This solution requires 3 tables:

- Users - contains user data (And a user ID).
- Links - contains link data (And a link ID).
- Clicks - many-to-many relationship between users and links.

That third table would look like this:

```
user_id | link_id | timestamp
-----------------------------
1       | 2       | ...
2       | 2       | ...
1       | 3       | ...
............
```

Comment: Hi Truth, thanks for the reply! :-) 

so in the "Users" table, I'd have the auto-incrementing ID in one column, and in the 2nd column the user name. The "link" table has an auto-incrementing ID in the 1st column and the link name (Video 1, Video 2, whatever) in the 2nd column. I am confused when it comes to assembling the "Clicks" table however. How do I pull in the data from the other two tables? I know this is very basic but MySQL is not my strong point. :-) Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, when a user logs in, the user ID is fetched from the database and stored in a session. When he clicks a link, he actually submits a GET form (i.e. www.example.com/index.php?linkid=1), which is where you get the link id. The stamp is the current time. :)

Comment: @TomC: Then, you can JOIN the results of a query to the third table, from the first and second, giving you a human readable report.

Answer (score 1):

why not just have

```
increment_ID
Account_ID
Link_URL
Timestamp
```

Then just insert a new record for each click.  You also don't need to manage links since you'll store the entire URL path

Comment: Hi Bones! Thanks so much for your input. I'm a bit confused by your description, though. Is your example in a single table?

Comment: @bones: Should the link URL change, your report is obsolete.

Comment: all you would need at the top of each page is insert into clicks (account_id, link_url, click_timestamp) values ($_SESSION['account_id'], "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]", now())

Comment: not really, since he's just looking for the last click anyway, he'd know what url he is looking for.